# How to make query with "contains" filter but also case insensetive?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a query filter that will return object that has column for example "FooBar" from database by passing argument "oobar". Haven't found it anywhere :(

Edit:
It turned out that "contains" is already case insensetive :O

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'ilike' to query like below

```
model.YOURMODEL.query.filter(Model.column.ilike("oobar"))
```

Comment: it doesn't work, only returns same strings - but case insensetive                                                 My code is return cls.query.filter(cls.username.ilike(username)).all()

Comment: Ok nevermind, my question was pointless. It turned out that "contains" is already case insensetive :O